# Setting up .htaccess file Apache

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess

I am honestly so lost with how to get this to work.

I have looked for days and everywhere seems to say something different and now I've got files with lines added that I can't even remember.

All I want is to remove the .php extension from the URL.. That's it..

I know I need a .htaccess file, but I don't know what exactly to write. This is what I have so far:

```
# Apache Rewrite Rules
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Add trailing slash to url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

# Remove .php-extension from url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php 

# End of Apache Rewrite Rules
</IfModule>
```

I have tried changing the file /etc/apche2/sites-enabled/000-default, but that doesn't seem to exist. There's a file 000-default.conf instead though, and this now reads:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
#ServerName www.example.com

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

<Directory /var/www/html>
            Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I can't remember if I've changed anything else, but it is not working. I just need someone to walk me through which files need changing and what to do because I have spent so long and I haven't done anything.

Answer (score 1):

To remove `.php` from your URL all you should need to use is this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Before you test this, make sure you've cleared your cache.